# How to embed 3rd party html page into the report?

Tags: html, iframe, jasper-reports

How can i create this code for Jasperstudio, to display a page (by url) on a iframe within the report?

Using a text box, and html component.

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>

<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

Any direction would be helpful, this is the idea i have so far.

```
<componentElement>
                <reportElement x="260" y="20" width="190" height="50" uuid="b7e534fb-15d5-4138-9522-793cf8d71afe">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.flash.element.allow.script.access" value="frame"/>
                </reportElement>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["page will be displayed here"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="190" height="50" uuid="b7e534fb-15d5-4138-9522-793cf8d71afe"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<a href='http://google.ca' target='frame'>click to go to google.ca</a>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to repost the same question

Comment: What is a original requirement/purpose? What is a difference between you have already done and you want to create?

Comment: Hey Alex, do you know how I can use the <hc.htmlContentExpression> to trigger by clicking the hyperlink from my text field and displaying it in a iframe?

Comment: Thank for the reply, I am trying to create a frame within the report  that can display a webpage. I have created a working hyperlink to google.ca, but I am trying to get the hyperlink target to display this webpage in a frame within the report. So I can make multiple links to target this frame, exactly like this http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

Comment: Please let me know If i am being clear or if i need to add any more information. Is there a way to define the frame?

Comment: Do you want to include the content of some page (html) to your report?

Comment: Yes, any ideas? I do need it be viewed within a frame, so i can add multiple hyperlinks.

Comment: I need to define the frame, so it can be targeted by a hyperlink.

Comment: The good sample of using *genericElement*: [Generic Element Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/genericelement/index.html#genericelements). You can also find 2 samples in *JR* package distributive

Comment: I literally want the page to be opened within the element, is this possible?

Comment: Did you try samples?

Comment: Yes Alex, I have tried the samples. It was helpful, I am now interested in uploading the hyperlinkReport.jrxml onto jasperserver. Then I can customize what I need to do from there! Please let me know If you have any idea on how to do this.

Comment: How can we fill a report that uses a one empty record data adapter?